# VIM: Set files to read-only when extracted by tar plugin

Tags: vim

Vim has `tarPlugin.vim` which defines a group of `autocmd`s that allow for browsing a tar file. I like this, but I want the contents of the tar file to be read-only by default rather than allowing me to edit them. (I sometimes do edits while reading for various reasons and I have an auto-save plugin on.)

Is there a way to make files vim extracts from a tar read-only by default?

What I've tried in .vimrc:

```
autocmd! BufReadPre tarfile::*/* set ro
autocmd! BufNew tarfile::*/* set ro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was close, but there's a quirk in how the tar plugin sets the file name that means the buffer doesn't have the `tarfile::` name at the time the buffer is created or before the contents are read in. (see `tar#Read` in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/tar.vim` for details.) The event to actually watch for is `BufFilePost`, so a working set of `autocmd`s *on Linux* is:

```
autocmd BufFilePost tarfile::*/* set ro
autocmd BufFilePost tarfile::* set ro
```

The `*/*` is another quirk that I got from looking at `tarPlugin.vim`. Apparently just `*` doesn't match file paths with `/` in them and you need *both* on Linux (and other UNIX-y systems), but `tarPlugin.vim` also leads me to believe you just need the `tarfile::*` pattern on a Windows, but YMMV.